# String to Struct variables in C , without pointer,define

Tags: c, string, variables

I want a way to convert a string to struct variable.

ex)

```
struct DAT
{
    int a,b;
    char c,d;
    float e,f;
}DAT1,DAT2,Main_data;

main()
{
    Test_function(1)
}

Test_function(int num)
{
    Main_data = DAT(num)   // If num is 1, Main_data = DAT1
}
```

---

I want this program.
But I can't use define and pointer.
This mean I don't use `*` and `#` operators.

How do I do this?

Comment: Ca you be straightforward and clear with example what you really want to achieve

Comment: `struct DAT dat_array[2]; Main_data = dat_array[num-1];`

Comment: `if ( num == 1 ) Main_data = DAT1; else Main_Data = DAT2;`

Comment: Note that modern C (meaning 'C written since about 1990') should have an explicit return type for every function — `int main(void)`, `void Test_function(int num)`, etc.  Yes, compilers do still allow the sloppy old notation — but that doesn't make it good style and C99 and C11 explicitly disallow 'implicit int return type'.

Comment: The struct type variable can add more. but I do not know that how does it rise more. How can I do this?... And, type error is my miss. Sorry.

Comment: What do mean by "add more"? Add more what?  Perhaps an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) problem?

Comment: DAT1, DAT2, Main_data are in the source, However variable can be added more. Example, DAT1-DAT2-DAT3-DAT4....DAT99. But I do not know how many will be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'compute' with variable names at runtime -- the names in your program really only exist at compile time and once your program is compiled, they're not available.  So you need to test the value and enumerate all the possibilities in your program if you want it to decide between different variables at runtime.  Something like:

```
void Test_function(int num)
{
    switch(num) {
    case 1:
        Main_data = DAT1;
        break;
    case 2:
        Main_data = DAT2;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid num %d for DAT\n", num);
    }
}
```

While this works, its verbose and error prone, which is why arrays and pointers exist -- they make it much easier:

```
struct DAT DAT[3], Main_data;

void Test_function(int num)
{
    Main_data = DAT[num];  // Undefined behavior if num is out of range!
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But The struct type variable can add more. but I do not know that how does it rise more. With this condition, How do I do this?...